# What law is violated when someone subscribes another person's email to several websites?

Tags: criminal-law

What law is broke if someone subscribes another person's email to several explicit websites?

Comment: What jurisdiction?

Answer (score 2):

Probably some privacy laws. They're interfering with your privacy by disclosing your personal information to other agencies without your consent. 
(This is in New Zealand, but most jurisdictions have privacy laws)